# Generate this kind of 2d burst or pulse

Tags: c++, math, 2d, cocos2d-x

I'm currently trying to develop a game using Cocos2d-x using C++
I really need to generate this burst or (donut-shaped) pulse.
I'm having a difficult time how to generate such shape.
At first, I was thinking of scaling the image but that didnt work out because the line or "diameter" of the donut shape gets bigger accordingly..
Any experienced coders who can provide an equation of this thing? or maybe "mathematics" is more exact.
If you guys can provide ANY help, suggestion, or alternative recommendation, I'll be so glad^^

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ewnEE5mt1ZM

Comment: It's called a circle. What do you want to know?

Answer (score 0):

I implemented something similar last year for a question on the cocos2d-x forums.

http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/textured-ring-implementation/23175

The class renders a repeated texture in a ring at a given inner radius with a thickness defined by the textures height multiplied by a thickness scalar.

I think this should meet your needs :)